# Cannot assign : must be a instance Django foreign Key error with html form

Tags: django

I am working with Foregin key . In dropdown I am passing Foregin key value.White storing data in table I am getting instance error

I tried to fetch data from relational table and pass that id .

models.py

```
class Contacts(models.Model): #client's point of contact
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

views.py

```
def add_contacts(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_dt = request.POST['user']   
        client_dt = request.POST['client']
        client = request.POST['client']
        name = request.POST['name']
        email = request.POST['email']
        phone = request.POST['phone']
        mobile = request.POST['mobile']
        role = request.POST['role']
        title = request.POST['title']
        print(user,client,name,email,phone,mobile,role,title)
        data = Contacts.objects.create(user=user,client=client,name=name,email=email,phone=phone,mobile=mobile,role=role,title=title)
        print(data)
        return redirect('contacts')
```

Comment: Hey, could you please show the `print` outputs?

Answer (score 0):

Probably do you can do that:

```py
def add_contacts(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_id = request.POST['user']   
        client_id = request.POST['client']
        name = request.POST['name']
        email = request.POST['email']
        phone = request.POST['phone']
        mobile = request.POST['mobile']
        role = request.POST['role']
        title = request.POST['title']

        data = Contacts.objects.create(
            user_id=user_id, # call user_id instead "user" only
            client_id=client_id, # call client_id instead "client" only
            name=name,
            email=email,
            phone=phone,
            mobile=mobile,
            role=role,
            title=title,
        )
```

Once `user` and `client` are foreign keys on `Contacts` model, do you can parse the `id` directly like above.

Another suggestion is to use the `get` dict function, to avoid some `KeyErrors`. I mean:

```py
request.POST.get('name', <default_value>) 
# instead
request.POST['name']
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because the `Model` expects an instance object for  `user` and `client` since both fields are [foreign keys](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey), so you would have to retrieve those to create your `Contacts` object (e.g. `Client.objects.get(pk=client)`).

By the looks of it (retrieving each field separately) you are not using Django [`forms`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/#working-with-forms). With that many fields and nested objects I would consider creating one and let the framework do its job, here is an example using [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/modelforms/):

forms.py

```
class ContactForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contacts
        fields = [
            "user", "client", "name", 
            "email", "phone", "mobile", 
            "role", "title"
        ]
```

views.py

```py
def add_contact(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # You probably want to redirect somewhere else
            return redirect("add-contact")
    else:
        form = ContactForm()

    return render(request, "add_contact.html", {"form": form})
```

add_contact.html

```py
...
<form method="post" action="{% url 'add-contact' %}">
    {%csrf_token%}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <button type="submit" >Create Contact</button>
</form>
...
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('contact/add/', add_contact, name='add-contact')
]
```